# How to prove that the convergence of the sequence $f_n(x) = \Big(1+\frac{1}{nx}\Big)^{nx}$ is not uniform.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Let  $f_n(x) = \Big(1+\frac{1}{nx}\Big)^{nx}$ for  $x\in (0, 1) $.

Obviously the sequence converges pointwise and the limit function is:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\Big(1+\frac{1}{nx}\Big)^{nx} = \lim_{t \to \infty}\Big(1+\frac{1}{t}\Big)^{t} = e = f(x).$$
However, convergence is not uniform, and one of the ways to prove that is by using the fact that $f_n(\frac{1}{n}) = 2$, but I don't know how to put it all together.
How to justify using $x=\frac{1}{n}$ as a counter example while trying to (dis)prove $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty }{\sup_{x\in (0, 1)}{\big|f_n(x)-e\big|}}=0$ ?

How does using $f_n(\frac{1}{n}) = 2$ prove that above mentioned supremum does not converge to $0$?

Please, help.

Comment: For any $n$, $$
\mathop {\sup }\limits_{(0,1)} \left| {f_n (x) - e} \right| \ge \left| {f_n (1/n) - e} \right| = \left| {2 - e} \right| > \tfrac{1}{2}.
$$ Thus, $$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \mathop {\sup }\limits_{(0,1)} \left| {f_n (x) - e} \right| \ge \tfrac{1}{2}.
$$

Comment: Thanks! I was going to ask how do we know this inequality holds, given that $f_n(\frac{1}{n})$ is not the highest nor the lowest value of that expression, but I guess it is sufficient to find at least one value which would give result different from 0, that holds for any n. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sup_{x\in (0,1)} |f_n(x) - e| \geq \left| f_n\left(\frac 1n\right) - e\right| = e-2$$
is bounded away from 0.